# How to use make to create and refresh a python virtual environment only when needed?

Tags: makefile, pip

I want to optimise the creation of and installation of python requirements.txt via pip inside a virtual environment via make.

The idea is that the pip install code should run only when the requirements.txt files were updated since the last execution.

I know that make is really smart regarding not recompiling tasks when the source files were not updated and in this case the source file would be the `requirements.txt` file.

How can I obtain this using `make`?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
.env: requirements.txt
    $(RM) -rf $@
    virtualenv $@ \
    && . ./$@/bin/activate \
    && pip install -r $<
```

As remarked by Etan Reisner (thanks!) the time stamp of the `.env` directory could change for other reasons, so you might want to use a flag file instead:

```
.env/made: requirements.txt
    $(RM) -rf $(@D)
    virtualenv $(@D) \
    && . ./$(@D)/bin/activate \
    && pip install -r $<
    touch $@
```

Comment: I'd use `$(@D)` instead of `$(dir $@)` (not `dirname` that trips me up *all* the time) for brevity (and to get `.env` and not `.env/` back) but other than that this looks exactly right.